# Hacker accessing PHP function through SSL by using exitant session

Tags: php, codeigniter, security, session

A person execute a PHP function through SSL by using curl. I added verification by IP adresse for session and I added HTTPS feature to the website, but even now that not working. I'm using CodeIgniter and I'm a C/C++ programmer, not a very good PHP programmer. Can someone tell me how the person does that?

I try to prevent it, but it wount stop.

Comment: You mean that your web can be accessed by typing something like `domain.com/class/function/parameter` using curl?

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the basepath is defined by adding the line `defined('BASEPATH') or exit("No direct script access allowed");` just after opening the PHP tag.

If it does not work you might have to consider .htaccess restrictions on the files in your project

Comment: It's not the file itself, CodeIgniter works like that, you can call a php function by using a linke like domain.com/class/function/parameter

Comment: @NoOne it is supposed to work like that. I now think i don't get your question. Can to explain further